# QPalette for beginners - where to start

Tags: python, pyqt, qpalette

I recently made my first python and PyQt program and now I'm looking to play with colors to make it look good. I've been looking around the documentation and the  [QPalette documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) seems to suggest that a QPalette is the way to go as opposed to manually setting the colors for each widget. Problem is I can't find a whole lot of info out there on how to use this in practice and while there is certainly a lot of data in the documentation for a beginner like me it is lacking in many examples!

From what I understand my goal here is to establish within a QPalette object the sort of "global" colors for my app, and then I assign that palette to all of my widgets right? So what is the best way to go about this? For example I want to set all of my buttons to a dark gray background. Looking at the documentation it seems you need to set the QPalette.button() color using .setColor but I'm not able to get this to work (see line #83). But I was able to set the background color of the dialog specifically just above that.

Here's just the Gui part of my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class BatchTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(BatchTable, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.setColumnWidth(1,50)
        self.hideColumn(1)
        self.hideColumn(3)
        self.hideColumn(4)
        self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QtCore.QString("Status;Alpha;File;Full Path;Process ID").split(";"))

class ffmpegBatch(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ffmpegBatch, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.pBar = QtGui.QProgressBar()

        self.edit = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        cmdGroup = QtGui.QGroupBox("Commandline arguments")
        self.alphaCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox("Output alpha as separate file")
        fpsLbl = QtGui.QLabel("FPS:")
        self.fpsCombo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.fpsCombo.addItem("29.97")
        self.fpsCombo.addItem("23.976")
        hbox1 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox1.addWidget(self.alphaCheck)
        hbox1.addWidget(fpsLbl)
        hbox1.addWidget(self.fpsCombo)
        cmdGroup.setLayout(hbox1)

        saveGroup = QtGui.QGroupBox("Output")
        saveLocationBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.outputLocation = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.popBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Pop dir")
        saveLocationBox.addWidget(self.outputLocation)
        saveLocationBox.addWidget(self.popBtn)

        saveBtnsBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        pasteFromClipboard = QtGui.QPushButton("Paste from clipboard")
        upOneBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("./")
        upTwoBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("././")
        saveBtnsBox.addWidget(pasteFromClipboard)
        saveBtnsBox.addWidget(upOneBtn)
        saveBtnsBox.addWidget(upTwoBtn)

        saveMasterBox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        saveMasterBox.addLayout(saveLocationBox)
        saveMasterBox.addLayout(saveBtnsBox)

        saveGroup.setLayout(saveMasterBox)

        self.runBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Run Batch Transcode")

        showDebugger = QtGui.QPushButton("Show debugger")
        showDebugger.setCheckable(True)

        self.mainBox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.table = BatchTable(self)
        self.mainBox.addWidget(self.table)
        self.mainBox.addWidget(cmdGroup)
        self.mainBox.addWidget(saveGroup)
        self.mainBox.addWidget(self.runBtn)
        self.mainBox.addWidget(self.pBar)
        self.mainBox.addWidget(showDebugger)
        self.mainBox.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.edit.hide()

        self.setLayout(self.mainBox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle('FFMPEG Batch Converter')

        # make pretty
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QtGui.QColor(40, 40, 40))
        self.setPalette(palette)
        palette.setColor(palette.button(), QtGui.QColor(100, 100, 100))
        self.runBtn.setPalette(palette)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ffmpegBatch()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you show your code so far?

Comment: Yeah, adding it to the original question. For example how would I make the "runBtn" background darker and the text white?

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, looks like [stylesheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) with cascading are a way better way to go. For example to set all buttons within the application to an absolutely beautiful yellow color: `QApplication.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background: yellow }")`